# Assigning multiple users to a workflow task in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, workflow-foundation, wss

Has anyone able to assign multiple users to a sharepoint workflow task using the CreateTask activity?

Answer (score 3):

Sharepoint task allow the use of groups. Assign the task to a group and trigger the work flow when a task has been assigned.

Answer (score 1):

I blogged a while ago about how to develop custom activities with multiple users.  It's been a while since I've done this, so I'm not 100% sure if it's applicable to your question, but it's worth a try:

[Multi Value Columns Solution #2 - Custom Activities in SPD](http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/04/multi-value-columns-solution-2-custom.html)

There's a useful discussion in the comments as well.

Hope that helps,
- Lee

Answer (score 0):

What version? WSS V3 or MOSS?

Is the "Create Task" bound to the Task List? If so then only one person at a time. Unless you have an AD group with a bunch of people or you modify the list to include SharePoint groups in the assigned to field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use group to grand permission to multiple users. The best way so far and I guess the only way to get it done easily.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a group is definitely the way to go if any user in that group can close the task.  On a side note if you need seperate tasks for multiple users, you can use a replicator with a custom activity / CreateTask activity.